# Название манного десерта. В кавычках или без?

Tags: выбор-слов

Рецепт манного десерта «Самали» или без кавычек и с маленькой буквы?

Comment: Может, всё-таки "С**о**мали", как название страны, народа и языка?

Comment: я вот не знаю...название такое..хотя глаз режет, согласна...А могу ли я изменить его?

Comment: *А могу ли я изменить его?* Сообщение отредактировать? Конечно можете! Или Вы другое что-то имеете в виду?

Comment: да нет, изменить название десерта...в данном случае в газете)

Comment: Моё предположение оказалось неправильным! Правильно через А! https://www.littlecookingtips.com/content/great-traditional-samali-greek-dessert :)

Comment: По-английски манка semolina, видимо, отсюда происходит и название дессерта.

Comment: греческий все же...в Интернете пишут, что рецепт с Египта...Спасибо!

Comment: Не за что! И Вам спасибо! Тоже узнал нового благодаря нашему обсуждению. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Есть статья **"Кавычки, господа, кавычки!"** В ней такая информация:

**Перечислим основные группы условных наименований, заключаемых в кавычки:**

...названия продовольственных товаров, в том числе алкогольных напитков. Обратите внимание: при употреблении **в качестве торговой марки** названия продовольственных товаров пишутся **с прописной буквы в кавычках**: вафли «Сливочные», **пирожное «Картошка», салат «Китайский»,** карбонад «Любительский», сыр «Моцарелла», соус «Тартар», ликер «Бейлис», вино «Божоле Нуво», вермут «Чинзано Бьянко», кофе «Черная карта». **Названия продуктов в бытовом употреблении пишутся со строчной буквы без кавычек:** любительская колбаса, бородинский хлеб, **салат оливье,** пирожное картошка. Без кавычек со строчной буквы пишутся и названия сортов вин, минеральных вод и др. напитков: мерло, шардоне, рислинг, портвейн, боржоми.

***В вашем случае лучше написать название десерта в кавычках и с большой буквы.***